# How to integrate products of beta distributions with large $\alpha$, $\beta$?

Tags: beta-distribution, integral, numerical-integration

I have a product of Beta distributions, like

$$\frac{1}{Z}\prod_{i}\frac{\left(x-A_{i}\right)^{\alpha_{i}-1}\left(B_{i}-x\right)^{\beta_{i}-1}}{\left(B_{i}-A_{i}\right)^{\alpha_{i}+\beta_{i}-1}\mathrm{B}\left(\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}\right)}$$

where $Z$ is a normalization constant and $\alpha_i,\beta_i \ge 1$. I need to integrate this in some finite interval $[a,b]$, where $a\ge \max_i A_i$ and $b \le \min_i B_i$.

When I try to do this with standard integration numerical packages, I keep getting underflows/overflows for large $\alpha_i,\beta_i$. What can I do?

Comment: Would it be possible to give us an example and more information about what you have tried? Are you using a Newton-Cotes rule for example (so polynomials of increasing complexity with a fixed  equi-spaced grid) or an adaptive scheme (eg. Gaussian quadrature)?

Comment: @usεr11852 I've been using GSL numerical integration routines. Specifically, https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/QAGS-adaptive-integration-with-singularities.html#QAGS-adaptive-integration-with-singularities.

Comment: Hmm this is a bit hard without seeing the code... Are you using RcppGSL or are talking pure C? Have you considered a Metropolis algorithm? Maybe MCMC-ing is an affordable choice in this case.

Comment: @usεr11852 I think Monte Carlo would be too slow. I am using pure C/C++. What is RcppGSL? I did not know it existed.

Comment: [RcppGSL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppGSL/index.html): `Rcpp Integration for GNU GSL Vectors and Matrices`, or in layman terms : *Write CPP code that uses GSL and integrate to it R*.